# distribution of censored multinomial variable

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, censoring

Let $F$ be a multinomial random vector of $n$ trials in $k$ categories. Let the random vector $C$ be defined as
\begin{equation}C_i \equiv \left\{\begin{aligned}
1 & \quad F_i>0 \\
0 & \quad F_i=0
\end{aligned}\right.\end{equation}

What is the distribution of $C$?

Comment: Hint: $C_i$ can have only two possible values.  It therefore is a Bernoulli variate and all you need to do is figure out the chance that $C_i=1$.

Comment: Yes but since $F$ is multinomial, I feel that the $C_i$ will be correlated to each other, which is not the case of a bernoulli variate if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sure, Bernoulli variables can be correlated. However, your comment has the salutary effect of illuminating the nature of your question and will help readers focus their answers (+1).